# Is there a Method to find datatypes of schema-less properties of a vertex in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

Is there a SQL method to find property datatypes for schema-less properties in OrientDB?

There is .type() or .javatype() which can be used against a property in a select query like -

```sql
"SELECT Title.type() from #36:1"
```

This only provides the type for non null properties. Any properties with Null value return no type information.

Also I tried method called 'getPropertyNames' in Javascript function as well (link below).

https://orientdb.com/javadoc/develop/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/OVertexDelegate.html#getPropertyNames--

I can use this in a function to pull out all property names but didnt find any similar method to pull PropertyTypes.

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();

var result = db.command('SELECT FROM V WHERE @rid = '+ id );
var fields = result[0].getRecord().getPropertyNames();
return fields;
```

Please provide guidance on how to get all property (schema and schema-less) property types for a Vertex record in OrientDB 3.0.

Either SQL method or Javascript Method and its usage will be very helpful.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL.html#query-the-schema

I think this could help you:

```
select expand(properties) from (
   select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
) where name = 'OUser'
```

And you could reference to the nummber of type (type column) here:
https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Types.html#supported-types